# How to write the code for a general B-spline function?

Tags: computational-geometry, splines

I write the code for B-spline basis and it works very nicely but now I need help to write code for general B-spline functions

[image: this is the generalized formula for B-spline function]

I would like the code to show the spline segment in this way:

[image: for specific value of t like 0<=t<=1,and the code use the b spline basis function only the interval which we are needed]

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of `Piecewise`.

Comment: p[t_] := Sum[pnt[[i + 1]] bspl[i, k, t], {i, 0, n}]    how can we change this for piece-wise i did not understand your comment of piece-wise .from this p[t_] i want only result when t belongs to [0,1).and that function use only basis function value which lies between [0,1)